# Regular expression to not allow spaces and specific strings

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a Regex in C# that doesn't allow spaces (at start, at end or in string) and specific strings in input value.

This is what I have: `@"^((?!string1|string2).)*$"`. This pattern validates input value contains `string1` or `string2` but does not validate spaces.

Invalid examples (Consider `_` as space):

```
someone@string1.com
someone@string2.com
someone@xyz.com_
_someone@xyz.com
some_one@xyz.com
```

I want to validate both cases in same regex. Where is my Regex wrong?

Comment: post some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: Invalid examples

"someone@string1.com",
"someone@string2.com",
"someone@xyz.com ",
" someone@xyz.com",
"some one@xyz.com"

Comment: post it in your question.

Comment: Aren't you complicating things a bit. I mean, just take the gut of your expression, and add spaces. `@"(string1|string2|\s)"` will match any string containing any of the words or any space charachter.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a space or better `\p{Zs}` to match just spaces (or `\s` to also match newline):

```
^((?!string1|string2|\p{Zs}).)*$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E((%3F!string1%7Cstring2%7C%5Cp%7BZs%7D).)*%24&i=someone%40string1.com%0D%0Asomeone%40string2.com%0D%0Asomeone%40xyz.com%20%0D%0A%20someone%40xyz.com%0D%0Asome%20one%40xyz.com&o=m)

Alternatively, you can use a negative look-ahead at the beginning of any anchored regex to disallow spaces (i.e. in order to match a string without spaces):

`(?!^.*\p{Zs}.*$)`

Your regex will look like

```
@"^(?!.*\p{Zs}.*$)((?!string1|string2).)*$"
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F!.*%5Cp%7BZs%7D.*%24)((%3F!string1%7Cstring2).)*%24&i=someone%40string1.com%0D%0Asomeone%40string2.com%0D%0Asomeone%40xyz.com%20%0D%0A%20someone%40xyz.com%0D%0Asome%20one%40xyz.com&o=m)